# Animate dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to animate my top nav.

At present the dropdown's just jump down on hovering the top nav links.

Dev site: http://goandco.w7.ext.starberry.com

I have tried the following:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( '.has-drop-down-a' ).hover(
        function(){
            jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideDown(200);
        },
        function(){
            jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideUp(200);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

My html is similar to the following:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="has-drop-down">
     <a href="#" class="has-drop-down-a">Search</a>
       <div class="drop">...</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need the class="drop" div to animate down, instead of being instantaneous.

***Edit:***

So, the following is working - except for 2 things:
1) you have to hover over the link once, then it'll work.
2) when you move the mouse down over the drop div, it collapses

```
 <script>
        jQuery('body').ready(function() {
            jQuery( '.has-drop-down-a' ).hover(
                function(){
                    jQuery(this).siblings('.drop').slideDown(400);
                },
                function(){
                    jQuery(this).siblings('.drop').slideUp(400);
                }
            );
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Put the relevant code in a jsFiddle. Don't put links to external sites that may not reflect the problem in the future.

Comment: The above link to the site does reflect the issue!

Comment: Use .siblings() instead of .children().

Comment: It reflects now, maybe not in the future when other users will check this question for further reference to a similar issue.

Comment: This is stated in the SO recommendations.

Comment: changes to siblings - getting there. but 1st hover is not right, works after a few. should I be using jQuery(document).ready(function() { ???

Comment: When you hover off the link the drop will collapse. That's exactly what your code is doing, so what were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in your code is not to include the 'div drop' INSIDE the 'a'.

The following should work:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="has-drop-down">
        <a href="#" class="has-drop-down-a">Search
            <div class="drop">...</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/61ewuhea/

**EDIT:**

Regarding the 2 problems:

**1)** you must set the initial state of drop to be collapsed, to do this, add

```
$('.drop').slideUp(0);
```

to the document ready function.

**2)** to solve this I highly recommend that you follow my advice and put the 'div' INSIDE the 'a' and use children instead of siblings.

Why? Because, unlike the website you provided, you want an animation, and because of that, you should try to "animate" one object only. That's why it collapses, you are saying "animate when I hover the 'a', not the 'div' ".

When you place the div INSIDE it no longer collapses since it's the same element.

One other problem that came out while doing the jsFiddle, is that you need a "bridge" connecting the 'a' element to the 'div' to do this, I simply added some css rules to the .drop class.

Here is the full javascript code:

```
jQuery('body').ready(function () {
    $('.drop').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.has-drop-down-a').hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideDown(200);
        },

        function () {
            jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideUp(200);
        }
    );
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="has-drop-down"> <a href="#" class="has-drop-down-a">
            Search
            <div class="drop">...</div>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.drop {
    background-color:#f00;
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
}
```

You can test the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/61ewuhea/1/

I hope this answers your question properly.

Comment: thanks... got it sort of working, but 2 issues above in my edit above

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the website documentation at http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/
In version 1.4.3, you can add more to your function.  Instead of:

```
jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideDown(200);
```

You can add more variables:

```
jQuery(this).children('.drop').slideDown( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Comment: So see my edited post above... working, but 2 issues